# Remove empty white line in between items (twentysecondcv)

Tags: spacing, ifthenelse

I am still quite a novice at using LaTeX. I'm currently using this particular template to write my CV 
https://www.latextemplates.com/template/twenty-seconds-resumecv

Sometimes I don't want to use the 4th argument of the `\twentyitem` command, which is defined as follows:

```
\newcommand{\twentyitem}[4]{%
#1&\parbox[t]{0.83\textwidth}{%
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize#3}\\%
    #4\vspace{\parsep}
    }\\
}
```

For example:

```
\begin{twenty} 
\twentyitem{2017}{IT course}{Foo}{}
\twentyitem{2010-2015}{Computer Science}{Foo}{Major in foo}
\end{twenty}
```

When leaving this 4th argument empty, it still produces an empty white line underneath the first line before moving on to the second item in the list. To conserve space I would like it to not produce this white vertical space. I am trying to redefine the argument as follows:

```
\newcommand{\twentyitem}[4]{%
#1&\parbox[t]{0.83\textwidth}{%
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{\\#4\vspace{\parsep}}%
        }\\%
}%
```

However this does nothing, the white space is not removed.

Here's a MWE (it uses the twentysecondcv class):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{twentysecondcv} 
\profilepic{} 
\cvname{} 
\cvjobtitle{} 
\cvdate{} 
\cvaddress{} 
\cvnumberphone{} 
\cvsite{} 
\cvmail{} 
\begin{document}
\aboutme{} 
\skills{}
\skillstext{}
\makeprofile
\section{Interests}
\section{Education}

\begin{twenty} 
\twentyitem{2017}{IT course}{Foo}{}
\twentyitem{2010-2015}{Computer Science}{Foo}{Major in foo}
\end{twenty} 

\section{Publications}
\section{Awards}
\section{Experience}
\section{Other information}
\subsection{Review}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem by using a more common class like `moderncv` or a similar one that's available on CTAN, or is the problem specific to this class? If not it would be better to change the MWE to a more common class.

Comment: Ah, and also as this is your first question: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{twentysecondcv}
\profilepic{}
\cvname{}
\cvjobtitle{}
\cvdate{}
\cvaddress{}
\cvnumberphone{}
\cvsite{}
\cvmail{}

\renewcommand{\twentyitem}[4]{%
    #1&\parbox[t]{0.83\textwidth}{%
        \textbf{#2}%
        \hfill%
        {\footnotesize#3}%
        \ifblank{#4}{\relax}{\\#4}\vspace{\parsep}%
    }\\
}

\begin{document}

\aboutme{}
\skills{}
\skillstext{}
\makeprofile
\section{Interests}
\section{Education}

\begin{twenty}
\twentyitem{2017}{IT course}{Foo}{}
\twentyitem{2010-2015}{Computer Science}{Foo}{Major in foo}
\end{twenty}

\section{Publications}
\section{Awards}
\section{Experience}
\section{Other information}
\subsection{Review}

\end{document}
```

[image]